# Java Endpoint Layer

Tags: java, rest

I have a REST application composed of endpoint layer, service layer and dao.

So commonly endpoint layer has all the annotations needed for your application such as @Path, @POST, @GET, etc..

is it a good practice to check the parameter in the endpoint whether it is null or empty?

for example..

```
@Path("/app")
public class EndpointLayerBean implements EndpointLayer {

   @EJB
   private ServiceLayer serviceLayer;

   @GET
   @Path("eq/{a}/{b}/eq")
   public Response getValue(@PathParam("a") String a, @PathParam("b") String b)
   {
     if(a == null || b == null){
        return Response.status(Response.BAD_PARAMETER);
     } else{
        return serviceLayer.doSomething(a, b);
     }
   }

}
```

Comment: Grenerally this is the right layer to do validation checks. But how can you check be reached if the path-parameter {a} and/or {b} is null. You path would be "/app/eq///eq"? I would exepect that you then get allways "404 - NOT Found" in your example?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that makes sense. But you should check out [JavaEE bean validation.](https://samaxes.com/2014/04/jaxrs-beanvalidation-javaee7-wildfly/) This will allow you to specify valid parameters via Annotations like this:

```
@GET
@Path("eq/{a}/{b}/eq")
public Response getValue(@PathParam("a") @NotNull String a, @PathParam("b") @NotNull String b) 
{
    return serviceLayer.doSomething(a, b);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's the right place to sanitaze the request for the basic level of conformity. If the DB has to be consulted, then the next layer with `@Transactional` annotation will be used.

Answer (score 1):

Yes in few cases, it completely depends on your datatype.
If a field has no value, it shall be null.
This one is quite trivial but is has a few nuances. Non existing numbers, strings are usually represented as null. But boolean fields without value should also be treated as false.